# Triggering Click Event on MS Access Command Button

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am building a MS Access front-end "application" which searches multiple other MS Access Databases.

The "secondary" database has a form with a couple of text boxes, in which the user enters search parameters, a command button that executes a query, and a ListBox into which the returned values are populated

For reasons of IT bureaucracy I am not able to modify the secondary databases.

I have got code working that opens the secondary database as an Access.Application object, and populates all of the fields on the form. I have also got code working that reads the output of the searches (from a ListBox control).

What I don't have is any working solution to the problem of clicking on the command button. If I could modify the "secondary" database then I would simply change the Click event sub to Public Cmd_Click() rather than Private Cmd_Click(), however I don't have that luxury.

I have tried using:

```
Cmd.SetFocus
Sendkeys("{Enter}")
```

and also

```
Cmd.SetFocus
Sendkeys(" ")

Cmd.SetFocus
Sendkeys("~")
```

Neither of these trigger the click event

Can anyone suggest a way of triggering a click event remotely?

I am using Access 2010

Comment: So you have access to the source code.. does that click handler implement the functionality directly, or is it *invoking* the desired functionality (as it *should*... in a dream world)? If the latter, then you could probably invoke that procedure rather than trying to simulate a click.

Comment: It invokes another sub, however that sub is private too

Comment: hmm.. ok so to clarify then - `Cmd` is an object reference to the button you're trying to "click"? Is that object owned by another instance of `Access.Application`? I believe `SendKeys` used unqualified like this, goes against `Application`, which would be your "current project" instance - if you can get ahold of the second `Access.Application` instance, and try invoking `SendKeys` off *that* `Access.Application` object....

Comment: What is the query that is executed? Anything else happen in that event? Can you just set links to the other db tables and build your own input form?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon SendKeys is a VBA library function, not a method of a particular Application object, so that is not the issue.

Comment: @Anastasia_DVG  Is the secondary database Access window visible AND the *active* desktop window?  Have you verified that the button is actually receiving focus?  In other words, could it be SetFocus rather than SendKeys that isn't working as expected?  Despite "rules" about focus, many times I have had to first (re)set focus to the form and then even call SetFocus on a control twice before it would actually receive focus.  I don't understand why, but Access's window functions are sometimes finicky.

Comment: @Anastasia_DVG  To elaborate on June7's advice about table links... Avoid opening the secondary database in its own Access object, rather link to its tables and recreate form logic in your new database.  If necessary, you could even copy the entire form from the secondary to the alternative "front-end" database.  As long as linked tables have the same name (and other referenced objects and code modules are present), you should be able to reproduce the entire form.  Perhaps you only need to duplicate the form's action code.  In that case, just write appropriate queries that manipulate data.

Comment: @CPerkins I'm fairly sure that you're right about the problem being with the active desktop window. I tried using SendKeys to write to the textboxes, and that didn't work (I had been accessing them as objects before which was fine). I'm looking into how to get the focus to the command button

Comment: @CPerkins possible. Do note that [`Excel.Application.SendKeys` is a thing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.sendkeys); I'm not very familiar with the Access object model, but if `Access.Application.SendKeys` is also a thing, then it likely takes precedence in the resolution order over the VBA standard library, so explicitly qualifying it with `VBA.` might actually invoke a different function in a different context than an unqualified call would.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon  I didn't know that about Excel.Application.SendKeys, but SendKeys is *not* a method of Access.Application.